# Service Causes SCM Error "reported an invalid current state 0"

Tags: c#, .net, service

I wrote a small service, which acts as a local network server. To write the service, I followed a [tutorial on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx), how to write a service using the `ServiceBase` class.

But when I register and start the service, I get error messages as shown below. I get exactly two of these error messages at the start and at the service stop. (Example = name of service).

> The Example service has reported an invalid current state 0.

Here a minimal sample of my service with all relevant parts. The code starts with an enum and struct definition which was provided in the MSDN tutorial:

```
public enum ServiceState
{
    SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
    SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
    SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
    SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ServiceStatus
{
    public long dwServiceType;
    public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
    public long dwControlsAccepted;
    public long dwWin32ExitCode;
    public long dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
    public long dwCheckPoint;
    public long dwWaitHint;
};
```

After this, the service code I wrote, reduced to the relevant parts:

```
namespace example
{
    public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service()
            : base()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "ExampleService";
            this.AutoLog = false;
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanShutdown = false;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = false;
            this.CanHandlePowerEvent = false;
            this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = false;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try {
                SetServiceState(ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING, 100000);
                // ... initialise and start...
                SetServiceState(ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING);
            } catch (System.Exception ex) {
                SetServiceState(ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            SetServiceState(ServiceState.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, 100000);
            // ... stop service ... 
            SetServiceState(ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED);
        }

        private void SetServiceState(ServiceState state, int waitHint = 0)
        {
            ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = state;
            serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = waitHint;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);
    }
}
```

The main entry point is simple as this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new Service());
}
```

As you can see, the number of error messages matches the number of `SetServiceState` calls. If I add additional such calls, the number of error messages increases accordingly.

So I assume, the whole problem is somewhere in the way I call the `SetServiceStatus` API, but I currently can't see the problem.

**Can you spot the Problem?**

Anyway is this the correct way to build a Service using C# and .NET?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First:

It is normally not necessary to call the `SetServiceState` method. It may be needed if your service really takes a long time to initialize (where you can tell the SCM you are still alive with `SERVICE_START_PENDING` and need a few more seconds) . Normally, you start a thread in `OnStart` and return asap.

I have written many services in C# the last years and never needed this.

But - I found a bug in the MSDN sample code (I tested your code myself).

In the `ServiceStatus` struct replace long with int or (better unit). If you use uint, you also have to change this in `SetServiceState`method.

Also see [Should DWORD map to int or uint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725547/should-dword-map-to-int-or-uint).

If you are interested in a small introduction how you can start with a Windows service in C# with an additional setup, you can check my blog entry:

http://www.rsprog.de/samplewindowsservice/

[Update 2018-01-20]

I created a new article about that, which uses the self-installation method which has the advantage (at least for me), that it does not need the setup project extension of Visual Studio

http://www.rsprog.de/windowsserviceselfinstall/

Comment: Great, thank you, this solved the problem. I'm usually aware how bad the MSDN documentation is, but here I just assumed this structure definition from the example is correct. You are also right, the manual status updates are not really necessary. The startup of my code took a long time in the first version, but I moved everything in a thread, because the outcome of some of these long processes are not relevant for the startup. Great blog entry, just the formatting of the step-by-step list gave me almost headache ;-).

Comment: Great, it worked for me. It is impossible to count how much errors MSDN has.... this was one among the infinite number...

Comment: Thanks so much, Rainer - I used Microsoft's sample code to create a service and hit exactly this problem straight away.  I've also added a comment to their page here (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756305(v=ws.10).aspx) pointing to your solution here.